# Custom Endpoint For Specific Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, permalinks, endpoints

I register a new post type

```php
register_post_type('movie', array(
    'labels'            =>  array(
        'name'               => __('Movies'),
        'singular_name'      => __('Movie'),
        'all_items'          => __('View Movies'),
        'add_new'            => __('New Movie'),
        'add_new_item'       => __('New Movie'),
        'edit_item'          => __('Edit Movie'),
        'view_item'          => __('View Movie'),
        'search_items'       => __('Search Movie'),
        'no_found'           => __('No Movie Found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Movie in Trash')
    ),
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'  => false,
    'capability_type'    => 'page',
    'hierarchical'       => true,
    'rewrite'            => ['slug' => 'movie'],
    'supports'           => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'has_archive'        => true
));
```

and my URL permalink set `Post name`. my movies are show on font page with `[mydomain]/movie/%postname%`. Now I want to do some sub-section in my movie post type only.

- `[mydomain]/movie/%postname%/artists/`
- `[mydomain]/movie/%postname%/songs/`
- `[mydomain]/movie/%postname%/news/`
- `[mydomain]/movie/%postname%/videos/`
- etc

and it also should support the `.../page/2/` E.g

- `[mydomain]/movie/%postname%/news/page/2/`
- etc

I try do do with

```php
add_action('init', 'my_custom_post_endpoint');
function my_custom_post_endpoint()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint('news', EP_PAGES);
    add_rewrite_endpoint('videos', EP_PAGES);

    add_rewrite_endpoint('news', EP_PERMALINK);
    add_rewrite_endpoint('videos', EP_PERMALINK);
}
```

But with this it work but `[mydomain]/movie/%postname%/news/page/2/` not working. I mean `.../page/2` not working.

Questions:

- How I can add endpoints for my `movie` post type only?
- How add support `.../page/2` after endpoint?
- List item

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your post type is **hierarchical**, so you could actually add `page-attributes` to the `supports` array in your post type args, i.e. `'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes')`, then you could create those sub-sections as child of your `movie` posts. But yes, the child posts will need to use unique slugs like `news`, `news2`, `news-3`, etc.

So if that's not preferred, then you may proceed to using the endpoint method.

But [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/) doesn't add the rewrite rules for pagination (the `/page/<number>` one and with the `EP_PAGES` place), so you might instead want to use [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) and have better control over the rewrite rules.

Here's an example, and you can test the RegEx (regular expression) pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/dbEM8e/1):

```php
function my_custom_post_endpoint()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^movie/(.+?)/(news|videos)(?:/page/(\d+)|)/?$',
        'index.php?movie=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules after applying the above code. Just visit the permalink settings admin page without having to click on the Save Changes button.